# React Router won't load pages without first loading the home page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am using React Router to navigate to different pages, each one being a different React Component. If I go to the home page first (e.g. /) then click a Link to take me to a different component (e.g. /new-guide), it renders fine. However, when I push the project to production using AWS or Netlify, accessing any component fails without first going to the home component.

Here's what it looks like in action. If you visit https://www.kelv.me/ then click the 'Gap Year' guide, the gap year component renders correctly. However, if you close the tab and try to visit https://www.kelv.me/gap-year directly, a 'Page not found' error occurs.

Here's my App.js:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import GapYear from './components/GapYear';

function App() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Router>
        <Fragment>
          <div id='content'>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={Landing} />
              <Route exact path='/gap-year' component={GapYear} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Fragment>
      </Router>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And here's my index.js:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: You are doing SSR? If you are not, you need to do server side rendering of your router.
More info here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-server-side-rendering

Comment: This is likely an issue with how you are serving your website. If it's only serving `index.html`, or whatever the root is called, then an initial load of https://www.kelv.me/ will serve that file and then handle routing in JavaScript. See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#notes-on-client-side-routing

Comment: Did you add the required `_redirects` file to [support client side routing](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#netlify).

Comment: Added both _redirects and SSR and it works now. Thank you all!